# Ruby on Rails remote_form_for with javascript disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`link_to_remote` has an `:href` option to unobtrusively add regular links just in case javascript is disabled.

Does `remote_form_for` have something like that?

Comment: I don't think any JavaScript helper in Rails 2 is unobtrusive.  What you are talking about is making them 'degrade gracefully'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [form_remote_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002177) explains how to do this:

> A "fall-through" target for browsers that doesn‘t do JavaScript can be specified with the :action/:method options on :html.